# Is there a way to use a Session variable in a non Web C# Project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a Website which uses 3 Projects, a web Project, a definitions project and a data project. Because I want to publish the Website in different languages I am using session variables to set the language. Now I have to translate something from the data project and I don't know how to set a session variable in it. It already worked in the web project with HttpContext.Current.Session but to use this method you have to use a Controller. Becouse I don't want to have controllers in the data Project I wanted to ask if there is another way to use Session variables for this Project...
I hope you can help me
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I've got your problem correctly, you have some troubles with layers/abstractions/architecture... Is the Data project something like Data Access Layer? Is it being used for accessing Data storage (Database)? If yes, it shouldn't know anything regarding UI stuff (session variable, HttpContext, e.t.c.).

So, ideally, the Controller should retrieve language from the Session object and pass to the Data layer as a parameter. Depends on that parameter, Data project should make a decision.

May be I was wrong regarding Data project definition...

Comment: I think you got it right just the Problem is that i don't really know how to get the retrieved language to the Data layer and how to make the variable a session variable there.

Comment: Can't you just use Resources file for translated content?
If no, again, Data Layer shouldn't use a session variable. Controller uses a DAL Repository, retrieves a session variable and pass as a parameter. So inside the controller there should be:

var language = .....;
var content = repository.GetSomeContent(language, 'some_parameter');

Ideally, you can move this logic into Business Service